# How to increase search speed for my vba userform?

Tags: vba

I have a userform for search values (Alphanumerical). It works good. but take long time and sometime hung-up excel program.

In my userform, there are three textbox and three Listbox.

for searching my query, I can type anything to any text box. and all data from three Listbox are filtered and dependent to each other.
For Example: On Userform Initilize, Each Listbox Show 100 Item List.
and when I type anything to any search box (Text box) Item will be filtered from all listboxes.

(Sorry, Maybe my english and grammar are very weak.)

try to understand with this image.

[image]

Is there any way to increase my search speed?

My code is below: -

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call loadList
    Me.tbox_srch_ID.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub tbox_srch_ID_Keyup(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Me.tbox_srch_Word.Value = ""
    Call loadList
End Sub

Private Sub tbox_srch_Word_Keyup(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Me.tbox_srch_Party.Value = ""
    Call loadList
End Sub

Private Sub tbox_srch_Party_Keyup(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Me.tbox_srch_Word.Value = ""
    Call loadList
End Sub

Sub loadList()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim baseArray() As Variant
    Dim resultArray() As Variant
    Dim IDArray() As Variant
    Dim wordArray() As Variant
    Dim PartyArray() As Variant
    Dim counter As Long, i As Long

    'On Error Resume Next

    'Clear current list boxes
    Me.lbox_ID.Clear
    Me.lbox_Word.Clear
    Me.lbox_Party.Clear

    'Assign source list to an array, unfiltered
    baseArray = Sheet2.Range("C2:E100001")

    'Set a default value to filter match counter
    counter = 0

    'Iterate through the source list, if search term is found add item to result array
    For i = LBound(baseArray) To UBound(baseArray)
        If ((InStr(1, baseArray(i, 1), Me.tbox_srch_ID.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 And Me.tbox_srch_Word.Value = "" And Me.tbox_srch_Party.Value = "") Or _
    (InStr(1, baseArray(i, 2), Me.tbox_srch_Word.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 And Me.tbox_srch_ID.Value = "" And Me.tbox_srch_Party.Value = "") Or _
    (InStr(1, baseArray(i, 3), Me.tbox_srch_Party.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 And Me.tbox_srch_ID.Value = "" And Me.tbox_srch_Word.Value = "")) Then

            counter = counter + 1

            ReDim Preserve resultArray(1 To 3, 1 To counter)
            resultArray(1, counter) = baseArray(i, 1)
            resultArray(2, counter) = baseArray(i, 2)
            resultArray(3, counter) = baseArray(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i

    'If there is at least one match, separate result array to two arrays and load them to the listboxes
    If counter > 0 Then
        ReDim IDArray(1 To UBound(resultArray, 2), 1 To 1)
        ReDim wordArray(1 To UBound(resultArray, 2), 1 To 1)
        ReDim PartyArray(1 To UBound(resultArray, 2), 1 To 1)

        For i = LBound(resultArray, 2) To UBound(resultArray, 2)
            IDArray(i, 1) = resultArray(1, i)
            wordArray(i, 1) = resultArray(2, i)
            PartyArray(i, 1) = resultArray(3, i)
        Next i

        Me.lbox_ID.List = IDArray
        Me.lbox_Word.List = wordArray
        Me.lbox_Party.List = PartyArray

    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: In your text you say 100 but the source range is 100k records?  How long does a search take right now?

Comment: Is there really 100,000 rows of data, or are you just grabbing more than you need? If you find the `lastRow`, you can use a smaller array which could help in speed. Also, if you pre-load your data into a `Dictionary`, you can save nearly ALL of the iterations searching for the value, at least in the Date column.

Comment: In each `Keyup` you clear one other textbox - why only one and not both of the other two?

Comment: Sir, I say 100 as an example. and I have only basic knowledge of VBA and English knowledge. so maybe I could not clarify my query.

Comment: You might want to consider using ADODB: query the spreadsheet and have data in `recordset` (single read), then use `filter` method of the `recordset` to filter as user types. That will require recoding everything with ADO and using SQL - including reads, writes to list, building filter string, ADO boilerplate for connections, etc., but it is likely to be substantially faster.

Answer (score 0):

`Redim Preserve` takes quite much resource, especially when running it 100K times. I'd collect the affected row numbers and store the data in an array in one step.

You should use a variable for checking upper boundary of For loop because `Ubound` is function and there's no need to evaluate it in every loop.

You should also revise the if condition, because it takes also a lot of resources. Please note that all conditions are evaluated (even if the bool logic would not require it) and you have 3 `InStr` (multiply with 100K).
Additionally, you check the textboxes for emptiness twice in each loop, for the 100K rows.

You might set an escape point somewhere, say when you find the first empty cell. No need to check empty area.

I would restucture it this way:

```
Dim RowColl as Collection
Set RowColl = New Collection

Dim boolID_Empty As Boolean, boolParty_Empty As Boolean, boolWord_Empty As Boolean
Dim boolSkip as Boolean
Dim iMax As Long

boolID_Empty = LenB(Me.tbox_srch_ID.Value) = 0  ' this is the fastest way to check for emptiness + check only once
boolParty_Empty = LenB(Me.tbox_srch_Party.Value) = 0 
boolWord_Empty = LenB(Me.tbox_srch_Word.Value) = 0
counter = 0

iMax = UBound(baseArray)
For i = LBound(baseArray) To iMax
    If LenB(baseArray(i, 1)) = 0 And LenB(baseArray(i, 2)) = 0 And LenB(baseArray(i, 3)) = 0 Then Exit For
    boolSkip = True

    If boolID_Empty And boolParty_Empty Then
       If InStr(1, baseArray(i, 2), Me.tbox_srch_Word.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then boolSkip = False
    End If

    If boolSkip And boolWord_Empty And boolParty_Empty Then
       If InStr(1, baseArray(i, 1), Me.tbox_srch_ID.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then boolSkip = False
    End If

    If boolSkip And boolID_Empty And boolWord_Empty Then
       If InStr(1, baseArray(i, 3), Me.tbox_srch_Party.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then boolSkip = False
    End If

    If Not boolSkip Then
       RowColl.Add i    ' add row index to a collection
    End If
 Next i

 counter = RowColl.Count    

 ReDim resultArray(1 To 3, 1 To counter)

 Dim v
 i = 0
 For Each v in RowColl    
     resultArray(1, i) = baseArray(v, 1)
     resultArray(2, i) = baseArray(v, 2)
     resultArray(3, i) = baseArray(v, 3)
     i = i + 1
 Next
```

Comment: **For Each i in RowColl**, gives a compile error. It says: For **Each control variable must be variant or object.**

Comment: That's true. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply Mr. @AcsErno. But I can't figure-out where to put this code or which line to delete from my old code etc etc.

Comment: I have deleted all Old Sub LoadList() code. Only keep Dim and  baseArray = Sheet2.Range("C2:E100001"), and paste your code. but it give subscript out of range error, error code 9.

Comment: And Sir, I have reposted my all code. Which is working but very very slow.

Comment: Just add listbox.clear clauses above  and listbox.list=... under my code. Which line gives you 9 error?

Comment: Sorry Mr. @AcsErno, I still didn't figure out. That's why I Repost My All VBA Code to this post. Actually I have only vary basic knowledge of ecxel vba. An You din not add any **Subroutine name**. Thats why I am confusing, where to put your code into my **Sub loadList()** subroutine or how many line to be deleted from my old code. etc.

Comment: Hey Mr. @AcsErno, It's highlight my **Sub loadList()** line and gives error 9, subscript out of range.