# Disable multiselection row in a listbox, Formatting Column in a listbox, and polulate listbox when search query clear from a textbox with vba

Tags: vba

I have a UserForm with a textbox for search query and a listbox for Search result.

below code is working good but when I clear all text value from textbox, it  doesn't repopulate my all data list as like user form initialize.

Other issue is when I click on a row it's highlight with blue background but when I click another row item it does not deselect the previous selection and all rows are highlighted.

and 5th, 6th and 7th column are Percent value but it show in decimal value in listbox.

**My code is so far.**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.ListBox1.AddItem "Product Name"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = "HSN Code"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = "Unit Type"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = "Rate"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = "CGST %"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = "SGST %"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = "IGST %"

ListBox1.List = Sheet6.Range("E3:K3000").Value

End Sub


Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value) = "" Then
ListBox1.List = Sheet6.Range("E3:K3000").Value
End If

Me.TextBox1 = Format(StrConv(Me.TextBox1, vbLowerCase))

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheet6
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim p As Long
Me.ListBox1.Clear
'FOR LISTBOX HEADER
Me.ListBox1.AddItem "Product Name"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = "HSN Code"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = "Unit Type"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = "Rate"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = "CGST %"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = "SGST %"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = "IGST %"

Me.ListBox1.Selected(1) = False

For i = 2 To sh.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To Len(sh.Cells(i, 5))
p = Me.TextBox1.TextLength

If LCase(Mid(sh.Cells(i, 5), x, p)) = Me.TextBox1 And Me.TextBox1 <> "" Then

With Me.ListBox1
.AddItem sh.Cells(i, 5)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = sh.Cells(i, 5)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = sh.Cells(i, 6)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = sh.Cells(i, 7)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = sh.Cells(i, 8)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = sh.Cells(i, 9)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = sh.Cells(i, 10)
End With

End If
Next x
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your problem, please add `Exit Sub` in the text box event after finding the text box value being empty:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

   If Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value) = "" Then
      ListBox1.List = Sheet6.Range("E3:K3000").Value
      Exit Sub
   End If
   'your existing code...
   '...
End Sub
```

The list box multi selection can be programmatically disabled, using `Me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle`, or manually  in the list box properties.

About formatting as percentage, please try the next way:

```
With Me.ListBox1
.AddItem sh.Cells(i, 5)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Format(sh.Cells(i, 5), "0.0%")
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = Format(sh.Cells(i, 6), "0.0%")
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = Format(sh.Cells(i, 7), "0.0%")
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = Format(sh.Cells(i, 8), "0.0%")
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = Format(sh.Cells(i, 9), "0.0%")
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = Format(sh.Cells(i, 10), "0.0%")
End With
```

Comment: Thank You Mr.@FaneDuru, You are my Favourite. You always solve my problems. Sir but how to format column and disable multi selection row?

Comment: @Prabhat Vishwas Please, test the updated answer and send some feedback.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Sir, You Solved my problem. Everything is working fine.

Comment: May I ask you for another help regarding this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67988985/how-to-increase-search-speed-for-my-vba-userform). If possible may you help me Sir?